# How to change [[NSBundle mainBundle] preferredLocalizations];?

Tags: ios

```
 [[NSBundle mainBundle] preferredLocalizations];
```

This value remains same even though I change my app language. Because of this `"Current location"` string of location annotation of map is showing in english after I change language to french.

Comment: This is a readonly property set based on iOS default localisation. To use localisation need to over ride this.